# id in jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have N inputs and for each input I have two buttons: 'start' with `class='starttimer'` and 'stop' with `class='endtime'`. When I press start and stop, the difference between those two clicks is saved in the input (in seconds).

```
<button style='color:yellow; background-color:green' class='buton starttimer' data-target='".$somethingUnique."' id='start_time_".$somethingUnique."'>START</button>
<button style='color:black; background-color:red' class='buton endtimer' data-target='".$somethingUnique."' disabled id='end_time_".$somethingUnique."'>STOP</button>
```

I have jQuery code which works but not correctly:

```
$('.start_time').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let time = new Date();
  t0 = time.getTime();
  return false;
});

$('.end_time').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let time = new Date();
  let t1 = Math.round((time.getTime() - t0)/1000);
  $("#" + $(this).data('target')).val(t1);
  return false;
});
```

This works but when I click the start button twice, it doesn't work correctly. How can I select by the ID? `start_time_".$somethingUnique.""`?

Comment: How are you generating the Input Fields on PHP side, there you could add a numeric id for each input

Comment: String concatenation in JS uses the `+` operator: `start_time_" + somethingUnique`, although I don't see how that in any way affects the problem you have. It would make more sense to keep the class selectors you have and instead store an array of timer values. If you could add your HTML to the question I can give you an example of what I mean, or possibly another alternative.

Comment: Not sure if it helps you since it's kinda unclear what you want to do with the id. But you can get the current clicked button with `$(this)` inside the event handler. Also your selector does not match the classes the buttons have.

Comment: I want that jquery works on id. But I don't know get the id in $('# here')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `id` of the button isn't really relevant to the issue. The problem is that you're only ever using a single set of variables for multiple buttons. Therefore if you click the 'start' button twice, or the 'start' of on set and the 'end' of another, you're going to have some weird behaviour.

To fix this it would be better to store the values within the elements themselves using `data` attributes, and then relate them to each other using DOM traversal methods instead of unique `id` attributes. Try this:

```js
$('.starttimer').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).data('start', new Date().getTime());
});

$('.endtimer').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $start = $(this).prev('.starttimer');
  var start = $start.data('start');
  if (start) {
    let end = new Date();
    let diff = Math.round((end.getTime() - start) / 1000);
    $(this).next('.output').val(diff);
    $start.data('start', null);
  }
});
```

```css
.starttimer {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: green;
}

.endtimer {
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">
  <button class="buton starttimer">START</button>
  <button class="buton endtimer">STOP</button>
  <input class="output" readonly="true">
</div>
<div class="timer">
  <button class="buton starttimer">START</button>
  <button class="buton endtimer">STOP</button>
  <input class="output" readonly="true">
</div>
```

Also note that I placed the CSS rules in an external stylesheet, as inline styling in HTML is bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard selection technique of jquery with matches elements that have ID starting with your required text.

```
$('[id^=start_time_]').click(function(e) {
  //put your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for info but that doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let t0 = 0;
$('[id^=start_time_]').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 let time = new Date();
 t0 = time.getTime();
 $('[id^=end_time_]').removeAttr('disabled');
 return false;
});

$('[id^=end_time_]').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 let time = new Date();
 let t1 = Math.round((time.getTime() - t0)/1000);
 $("#" + $(this).data('target')).val(t1);
 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button style='color:yellow; background-color:green' class='buton starttimer' data-target='somethingUnique' id='start_time_somethingUnique'>START</button>
<button style='color:black; background-color:red' class='buton endtimer' data-target='somethingUnique' disabled id='end_time_somethingUnique'>STOP</button>
 
  
<input id="somethingUnique" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to create multiple timers then i think your approach with the id's is wrong. Although it's good you made the id's unique. It seems you do that with php which makes it harder to know what the id's are on the client side (in javascript). But you can do this without id's too.

I used a div as a wrapper for the buttons and inputs that belong to each other. I used a hidden input to store the starttime, but you could use a data attribute too.

With the code snippet below you can create multiple timers, without having to worry to press the start button twice. Even when you don't set the start button to disabled then it will just reset the timer belonging to that button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.starttimer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wrapper = $(this).parents('.timerWrapper');
    var currTime = new Date();
    
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    wrapper.find('.endtimer').prop('disabled', false);
    
    wrapper.find('.time').val('');

    wrapper.find('.starttime').val(currTime.getTime());
    return false;
  });

  $('.endtimer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wrapper = $(this).parents('.timerWrapper');
    var currTime = new Date();
    var startTime = wrapper.find('.starttime').val();
    
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    wrapper.find('.starttimer').prop('disabled', false);

    wrapper.find('.time').val((currTime.getTime() - startTime) / 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.starttime {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timerWrapper">
  <input class="starttime" />
  <input class="time" />
  <button class="starttimer">START</button>
  <button class="endtimer" disabled>STOP</button>
</div>

<div class="timerWrapper">
  <input class="starttime" />
  <input class="time" />
  <button class="starttimer">START</button>
  <button class="endtimer" disabled>STOP</button>
</div>
```